# How to view .PVR textures? (for Leopard)

Tags: ios, macos, osx-leopard, viewer, quicklook

I’m using Leopard. I already tried QuickLook plugins like [QuickPVR](http://www.limbic.com/quickpvr.html) and [PVRUncrush](http://www.quicklookplugins.com/2009/10/18/pvr-textures/), and they don’t work, as in nothing happens when I QuickLook. Also [TexturePacker](http://www.texturepacker.com) wouldn’t install in Leopard.

Oh, the textures are compressed using [PVRTexTool](http://www.imgtec.com%2Fpowervr%2Finsider%2Fpowervr-pvrtextool.asp)

Anyone with ideas?
Please and thank you.

Comment: Isnt XCode showing them? In my setup XCode displays pvr files.

Comment: xcode does, I'm using Unity, it shows it too, but I'm looking for a view for the Finder. thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about viewer tools, but since PVR is just a compression format, you could use the PVRTex lib from PowerVR (free if you register on their site) to quickly write your own tool that decompresses the file and shows it in a window.

Alternatively, there is KaniTexTool (https://github.com/KageKirin/KaniTexTool) that could be used as a base for such a viewer.

An other way would be an app on iPhone that reads in the file from a webserver and displays it without any decompression since the PVR format is natively supported.